# Unable to fetch the CLI MOTD and remote config - firebase Hosting

Tags: angular, firebase

When I login and init, this item does not appear, has anyone encountered such a problem? What is the solution?

> Hosting : Configure and deploy firebase hosting sites

[image]

Comment: It's the 4th one? You can enter NO when it asks if you want to setup Github actions.